# Google map API geocode

Tags: javascript, api, geocode

I am trying to fix this code in the below.
From here I understand top part of if statement is working fine, 
but after else part all I can see is a declared variable but this variable has not been used.

What I tried to do is getting geocode (Lat and Lng) from an address then mark on the map.

I want to know how I have to use this variable.

Now, with the code, map can still mark the point but map centre is wrong.
I have to zoom in multiple times to locate this point.

Can anyone help please?
Thank you

```html
function addMarkerByAddress(supplier_id, address, infoWindowHtml, latitude, longitude)
{
    current_supplier_id = supplier_id;
    if (latitude != 0 && longitude != 0)
    {
        var point = new GPoint(latitude, longitude);
        var marker = new GMarker(point);
        GEvent.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
            marker.openInfoWindowHtml(infoWindowHtml);
        });
        map.addOverlay(marker);
    }
    else
    {

        var addressLatLng = geocoder.getLatLng(address, function(point)
    {
            if (point)
            {
                var marker = new GMarker(point);
                GEvent.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
                    marker.openInfoWindowHtml(infoWindowHtml);
                });
                map.addOverlay(marker);

                jQuery.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
            url: "/ajax_request",
            data: "action=updateSupplierLocation" +
                "&supplier_id=" + current_supplier_id +
                "&latitude=" + point.x +
                "&longitude=" + point.y

        });
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Please for the love of all good things reformat your code to use a 2 or 4 space indent and align your braces consistently!

Comment: I am so sorry, I should've cleaned things out before I posted it and thanks for editing. I will be concerning about this in the future.